# Form Submit with JS Not Posting to Controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I would like to 'post' a form with vanilla JS. There are other questions similar, but I cannot get mine to work. The data is simply not passing to the controller.

I have several options for user on page, displayed as buttons. When the user clicks one button, a hidden form gets filled, and then the JS will submit the form to the controller.

the hidden form below:

[for testing, I have not 'hidden' the form fields yet, so I can monitor the correct information is getting to the form]

```
<form action="RetailTimePriceDisplayOne" method="post" id="postForm" name="postForm">
    <input type="text" id="fmZero" value="@ViewBag.zero" />
    <input type="text" id="fmVehicle" />
    <input type="text" id="fmTeam" />
    <input type="text" id="fmTLabor" />
    <input type="text" id="fmRouteCost" />
    <input type="text" id="fmRouteD" value="@ViewBag.vehicleMile"/>
    <input type="text" id="fmRouteT" value="@ViewBag.vehicleTime"/>
</form>
```

My JS:

```
<script>
    function fillForm(vehicleType, teamCount, travelLabor, routeCost) {
        document.getElementById("fmVehicle").value = vehicleType;
        document.getElementById("fmTeam").value = teamCount;
        var x = @ViewBag.rateTravelDrvr;
        if (teamCount > 1) {
            x = @ViewBag.rateTravelDrvr + (@ViewBag.rateTravelCrew * (teamCount - 1));
        }
        document.getElementById("fmTLabor").value = x;
        var y;
        if (vehicleType == "V") {
            y = @ViewBag.vVPrice;
        }
        if (vehicleType == "H") {
            y = @ViewBag.vHPrice;
        }
        if (vehicleType == "T") {
            y = @ViewBag.vTPrice;
        }
        document.getElementById("fmRouteCost").value = y;

        SubmitForm();
    }

    function SubmitForm() {
        var myForm = document.getElementById('postForm');
        //document.forms["postForm"].submit();
        myForm.method = 'post';
        myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

The form gets filled correctly, but no data is submitted to the controller. You can see that I played around with it a bit. One thought I had was that the method was changing to 'get' and that by explicitly specifying the method, I might solve the issue. But no such luck. Thanks!

EDIT:
As requested, one of the 6 buttons on the page that fire the JS function.

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" style="width:100%; height:100%;" onclick="fillForm('T',3)">
                <strong>@ViewBag.TrkThr</strong>
                <p>with 3 persons</p>
                <p>+ @ViewBag.TrkMinute per labor minute*</p>
            </button>
```

Comment: specify proper enctype attribute for your backend

Comment: @Deadooshka huh. didn't think about that. can you show me an example?

Comment: @Deadooshka I tried enctype="text/plain" and didn't work

Comment: I wonder you don't specify the name attrs on the inputs. It's basics.

Comment: @Deadooshka uhh cuz im an idiot, and i forget basics....and that works. submit answer please

Comment: Could you please share the controller codes?  What you mean not posting to controller. Do you mean you couldn't find the model data inside the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "name" of the inputs wasn't defined, and hence data wasn't getting posted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I want to submit the form, I am using button, then do onClick event

Comment: I have a button with an onClick event, but I didn't put the code up. I will edit now